# check for duplicate on lose focus in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, duplicates

I am trying to write a data input app using Visual Studio 2017 C# for my company.
We have 2 tables, SI and SIC, in a SQL DB.
I have created a form and put a bound datagridview, which is bound to the SIC table.
On form load, it shows all data nicely.
What we want to do is enter data into this datagridview and save.
However, when entering a value into column D, we want to check that it doesn`t exist in column D in the SI table.

I did have it setup with a unique constraint, however, when the record wasn`t unique, an error message appeared, and pressing OK would delete all the other data on the row. Not desirable as there is quite a lot of data to be entered.

I am very new to programming in general, so would appreciate any advice that could be given.
My form code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Product_List
{
    public partial class NewProduct_frm : Form
    {
        public NewProduct_frm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void NewProduct_frm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'bHTESTDataSet.SIC' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.TableAdapter.Fill(this.bHTESTDataSet.SIC);
        }

        private void Save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.BindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.bHTESTDataSet);
        }

        private void Reload_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.TableAdapter.Fill(this.bHTESTDataSet.SIC);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use the CellValidating and CellEndEdit events, like in this example? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-validate-data-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control

Comment: My general advise is to keep this kind of logic to the DBMS. Data Consistency (inlcuding uniqueness of any Row) is it's job. Moving it to the client will only get you into Race Conditions and multiple clients not doing that properly/the same way. I prefer to have my UI accept anything and overall leave the checks to the DBMS when I try to INSERT it.